# How can I change logfile path of phantomjs with selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs, webdriver-io

When using phantomjs with selenium, I would like to change the default --webdriver-logfile parameter, that selenium passes to phantomjs. How can I do it?

The corresponding line in selenium log:

```
11:06:06.960 INFO - arguments: [--webdriver=14380, --webdriver-logfile=<ROOT PATH DELETED HERE>/phantomjsdriver.log]
```

Firing up phantomjs in coffeescript:

```
webdriverio = require 'webdriverio'

module.exports.World = World = (next) ->
  @browser = webdriverio.remote({ desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs'
    "phantomjs.binary.path": "node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs"
  }})
  .init()

next()
```

Comment: Are you using the javascript language-bindings or something else?

Comment: Javascript. With webdriverio, if it matters.

Comment: @molnarzs please show how do you fire up `PhantomJS` driver from javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for few hours and could not find the answer, therefore I have hacked it in the phantomjs file that is called by selenium. This is not a proper solution but does the job.

```
args = args.map(function(str) {
 if(str.search('-webdriver-logfile') != -1 ) {
    console.log('Replacing default webdriver log with null in phantomjs');
    return str.replace(/--webdriver-logfile=.*$/i,"--webdriver-logfile=/dev/null")
 }
 return str;
 });
```