# How to change the logfile path of phantomjs through selenium?

Tags: perl, selenium, phantomjs

i ran into a problem that seems to be a bug in selenium but maybe someone can hint me to a solution anyway.

A similar question has been asked 11 months ago see: [How can I change logfile path of phantomjs with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804745/how-can-i-change-logfile-path-of-phantomjs-with-selenium)
but it was not solved.

I'm using Selenium::Remote::Driver in Perl to connect to selenium. My code looks like this:

```
    my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver(
    'remote_server_addr' => 'localhost',
    'port' => "4444",
    'browser_name' => 'phantomjs',

    extra_capabilities => {
        'phantomjs.cli.args' => ['--webdriver-logfile=/tmp/phantomjsdriver.log']
    }
);
```

I found out that the phantomjs devs have integrated the parameter phantomjs.cli.args to pass parameters through to phantomjs. The parameters show up but unfortunately are added to the default parameters.

See the logfile of selenium:

```
10:20:29.207 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{platform=ANY, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, phantomjs.cli.args=[--webdriver-logfile=/tmp/phantomjsdriver.log], browserName=phantomjs, version=}]
10:20:29.208 INFO - executable: /usr/local/node/bin/phantomjs
10:20:29.208 INFO - port: 5710
10:20:29.208 INFO - arguments: [--webdriver-logfile=/tmp/phantomjsdriver.log, --webdriver=5710, --webdriver-logfile=/phantomjsdriver.log]
10:20:29.208 INFO - environment: {}
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
Unable to open file '/phantomjsdriver.log'
```

On the 4th line you can see that my argument was passed but the default '--webdriver-logfile=/phantomjsdriver.log' is also part of the arguments.

I tried also to set the loglevel to NONE but it tries to open the logfile anyways.

Lastly i tried to start phantomjs with a config file but i couldn't figure out the config option for the logfile and i'm not sure that would help.

My selenium server runs as a daemon if that is important.

Any help is appreciated!

Have a nice day

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805635/change-path-for-the-logfile-of-phantomjs-in-java see @Siul's answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `new_from_caps` method for full control of your driver instance? Using this option no defaults are assumed by the constructor.

e.g.

`my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new_from_caps(
    desired_capabilities => {
        'browserName' => 'phantomjs',
        'phantomjs.cli.args' => ['--webdriver-logfile=/tmp/phantomjsdriver.log']
    }
);`

See doc here: https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver#new_from_caps

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work. Even using this method, the default webdriver-logfile argument is still appended to the phantomjs call.

I was unable to find a simple workaround either.